# EU cookie law: "Asking" permissions in TOS

Tags: cookies

Can I just put something like "You give MYAPP permissions to save cookies to your computer" into my TOS, to comply with the EU cookies law?
And then when user first comes to my app, i will ask the user to accept my TOS.

Comment: Erm.. Can you add some text to your web page? Who knows but you...

Comment: I mean, will my app then comply with the EU cookies law?

Comment: We are programmers, not lawyers. Never take the word of anyone but a certified lawyer in any matter regarding the law, or you'll be the one who pays for it. That being said...... What "EU cookies law"?

Comment: http://www.aboutcookies.org/Default.aspx?page=3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law and not programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this insightful article from a known Web Analytics Specialist.

http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/2011/05/20/google-analytics-and-the-new-eu-privacy-law/

It's still not clear how this law is going to be enforced, and of course a lawyer would be the better person to help you here. But If you can't get a lawyer on your site to help you out with this matter and you want to stay on the safe zone, maybe the best option is to copy the way ICO works around this.

http://www.ico.gov.uk/

They just set a ASP session cookie and the analytics code is only present on the page if you strictly allow it. The ICO website shows a banner at the top with information and privacy link,s along with the form to turn on the tracking.